# What is the difference between min and minOf in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, syntax

In my legacy code I have this:

```
java.lang.Math.min(a, b)
```

I'd like to replace it with Kotlin equivalent, but I'm a little confused which one should I use. I found these two:

```
kotlin.math.min(a,b)
kotlin.comparisons.minOf(a,b)
```

As I noticed, both of them internally call `Math.min`. Is there any difference between them that I miss? Is one of them preferred for future use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kotlin [kotlin.math.min(a,b)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/min.html) takes concrete types like `Int`, `Double`, `Float`, `Long` and compares them mathematically.

Kotlin [kotlin.comparisons](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/min-of.html) `fun <T : Comparable<T>> minOf(a: T, b: T): T` takes a generic type `T`, that extends the interface `Comparable<T>`. This can be used in collections to sort them, based on the implementation of [Comparable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/) on that class.

**Which to use now?**

As you see, `kotlin.comparisons.minOf(a,b)` is a more generic implementation than `kotlin.math.min(a,b)`. If you are using number types it does not really matter which to use, as both are implemented with `Math.min(a, b)` as you already pointed out.

Comment: `So if you do not have a type that is used in a collection and just wanna get the smaller value of two numbers you should go with kotlin.math.min(a,b).` - but why? You explained the differences, but no reason why he should use it.

Comment: @Vojtěch you are right. I adjusted my answer.